# How can I prevent users pasting inside buttons when a custom style is applied?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I've recently applied a style to all my buttons within my `style.xml` using: `<item name="buttonStyle">@style/buttonStyle</item>`. When I do this, its suddenly allowing user's to paste text within the button itself, replacing the text inside the button entirely. Of course this is not ideal and I would like to prevent this from happening.

When there is **no** style applied, the buttons operate properly.

Any **long** press either side of the text within the button results in the option being provided as seen below:

[image: Shows where the user is allowed to paste]

The button after having the text pasted:

[image: Shows the pasted text in the button]

This is the code of the `@style/buttonStyle`:

```
<style name="buttonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cabin_condensed_semibold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_primary</item>
</style>
```

This is the code of the background `@drawable/button_primary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/medium_button_no_border"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And finally the `@drawable/medium_button_no_border`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/white">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/lightGrey" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

I've tried to add attributes like `<item name="android:editable">false</item>` but this doesnt seem to make a difference. The problem also still persists if I remove the parent `Widget.AppCompat.Button` from my `buttonStyle`.

Comment: @Zoe okay, my bad.

Comment: @Zoe also, why do you keep removing me saying 'I appreciate any help, thankyou.' what's wrong with that?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/6296561

Comment: You could try to remove the `item`s from the style one by one to check which one of them is causing the problem, or if just applying an empty style is enough

Comment: @lelloman yeah removing `items` one by one helped to solve it, thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `@style/buttonStyle` the attribute: `<item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>` was making the button text editable. This attribute supposedly 'capitalizes every character' but didn't actually capitalize anything.

I just replaced this with: `<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>`. Now the text in the button is not editable and is capitalized.